# When converting Activity to AppCompatActivity why is there no menu.main, and how do I replace it?

Tags: javascript, android-activity, android-menu, appcompatactivity

I am very new to Android development. I am following a tutorial https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5sEeprYnHa8 and want to do it using the AppCompatActivity instead of the older Activity. I want to inflate the menu, although I have no idea why menu is not automatically in the res folder. It cannot resolve the symbol menu_main.xml What exactly should I do in this situation? What is going on? Thanks.

```
package com.example.android.cameraattempt;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.provider.MediaStore;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.VideoView;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private Button mRecordView, mPlayView;
private VideoView mVideoView;
private int ACTIVITY_START_CAMERA_APP = 0;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    mRecordView = (Button)findViewById(R.id.PlayButton);
    mPlayView = (Button)findViewById(R.id.RecordButton);
    mVideoView = (VideoView)findViewById(R.id.videoView2);
    mRecordView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v){
            Intent callAppVideoIntent = new Intent();
            callAppVideoIntent.setAction(MediaStore.ACTION_VIDEO_CAPTURE);
            startActivityForResult(callAppVideoIntent, ACTIVITY_START_CAMERA_APP );
        }
    });
    mPlayView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v){
            mVideoView.start();
        }
    });
}

protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data){
    if(requestCode == ACTIVITY_START_CAMERA_APP && resultCode == RESULT_OK){
        Uri videoURI = data.getData();
        mVideoView.setVideoURI(videoURI);
    }
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu){
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu_main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item){
    int id = item.getItemId();
    int action_settings = 0;
    if(id == action_settings){
        return true;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

1. The Menu is directly will not come because now the Android Studio is not creating the menu. In the video see the provision for specify the menu resource at 01:32 sec. https://youtu.be/5sEeprYnHa8?t=92 . This option is currently not there in new studio.
2. For your issue where "cannot resolve the symbol menu_main.xml",  I hope you already have menu_main.xml file present in your project.

   - If file menu_main.xml Already Present.

     1. create a folder under "res" with name "menu".
     2. place the "menu_main.xml" inside the "menu" folder created.
     3. In you java code

        ```
        @Override
        public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu){
            getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
            return true;
        }
        ```
   - If file menu_main.xml NOT Present.

     1. create a folder under "res" with name "menu".
     2. create a file "menu_main.xml" inside the "menu" folder created.
     3. place below xml code inside menu_main.xml (you can modify if needed)

           `<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
             <item android:id="@+id/about" android:title="About" />
             <item android:id="@+id/help"  android:title="Help" />
           </menu>`
     4. In you java code

        ```
        @Override
        public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu){
            getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
            return true;
        }
        ```

Comment: Thanks! I now find it odd that action_settings is an item here [link]( https://developer.android.com/training/appbar/actions.html), but in my code it does not come up automatically in the list and cannot be resolved. Also app is not bound when I take this piece of code.` <!-- Settings, should always be in the overflow -->
    <item android:id="@+id/action_settings"
          android:title="@string/action_settings"
          app:showAsAction="never"/>`I am using Android Studio 2.3.3 and updating Nouget which is not as quick as the title "Quick Fix", so I must wait to experiment.

Comment: In menu_main.xml alt enter solved the problem with app, but action_settings cannot be resolved. In MainActivity.java all occurrences of R is not unresolved.

Comment: I found out that in menu_main.xml @string/action_settings can be replaced with "Settings" which will remove the error and R will work again. If you create a <string name = "action_settings">Settings</string> in res/values file and have @string/action_settings in menu_main.xml, you can use strings files different foreign languages. I got this from my helpful new book "Android Application Development For Dummies: All in One". lol